# fully Customized Editprofile.aspx SP2010

Tags: 2010, user-profile, custom, user-controls

I have to customize the EditProfile.aspx page that under the 14 Layouts hive.
I know I can add fields in the user profile and make them show in the edit page , but this is a little more that what could be offered from the OOB feature. 
Apart from the detail fields that are already shown to us in the edit profile , i also need to show some custom fields and from different LOB application and do some data magic and pass it on to the Service, that would update records in user profile and hence send it to another Line of Business for synchronization.

So, to make a small story short, what ever is shown in the Edit profile + "My own custom fields based on the user who log's in".

I need some tips on how to get started and overwrite the page EditProfie, (Assuming I want to overwrite and induce my fields along with the fields that are already present and call a submit button functionality which calls the service and not a javascript postback the way SaveandClose button does at the bottom left of the page.

Any links or working examples would be really appreciated.

Also is there a way to by pass the save and close button hide it through Jquery and have your button renedered.

Thanks
Rahul

Answer (score 1):

This is basically the same question as asked and answered in [How do I add a custom control to the My Site person.aspx page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17948/how-to-edit-the-person-aspx-page-without-using-sharepoint-designer/)

Check out that question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to other thread, but that doesn't gives me the slightest hint. There is more to it. I initially thought of deriving the class, and override some or many methods it exposes. but it is sealed. as the base class ProfileUi gives limited functionality. I was wondering what steps i should take if i would have to write my own from start to end and linking back and forth from the person.aspx.
Thanks anyway for pointing out.